# wsl kali sudo locked after update

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, sudo, validation

I'm running kali on wsl2.  I had just run an upgrade (sudo apt upgrade), which included the line:

> Updating /root/.profile to current default.

The update process ended with an error code:

> /usr/bin/perl: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypt.so.1:
> cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> dpkg: error processing package libc6:amd64 (--configure):
> installed libc6:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess
> returned error exit status 127
> Errors were encountered while processing:
> libc6:amd64
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Subsequently, I'm locked out of sudo:

> kali@L-157877:/etc$ sudo apt install -y kali-win-kex
> sudo: account validation failure, is your account locked?

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Using the `wsl` command you can specify the user IIRC. // But in the first place, what exactly did you upgrade how exactly? This sounds like you have an inconsistent system now.

Comment: The original upgrade was:
sudo apt upgrade

Comment: [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment